# how to implement cross-component upload progressbar in AngularDart

Tags: file-upload, dart, progress-bar, angular-dart

I have been implementing a small AngularDart projecjt which contains serveral components. One of those components can upload file to server. I would like to implement an upload progressbar that keep upload the file and show upload progress while user navigate to other components. (like other file upload website such as Dropbox, Google Drive. User can go to other section of website while the uploading keep working). Is there any guide or solution to implement such functiionality? (For now, I can implement asynchronous upload and progressbar yet.The Problem is get it to work across components.)

Thanks for any help. :)
PS. sorry for my broken English.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your GUI in a view and place it using `ng-view`. When you put your progress bar outside the of the ng-view it should stay on the screen when the view changes.